# Having composer, npm, gulp how do I set up TinyMce properly?

Tags: gulp, tinymce

I have a php project and I use composer for php libraries and npm/gulp for CoreUI. 
CoreUI doesn't have TinyMce so I installed it with npm. The files are now inside node_modules folders, but I think they should be moved outside.

I have 2 options:

1. use composer to set up TinyMce anywhere I want, probably
2. use gulp to move/copy outside node_modules

I believe the recommended solution is to copy with gulp but I am not sure how, which files and where.

1. How do I copy with gulp?
   tried without success

   gulp.task('copy', function () {
       gulp.src('./node_modules/tinymce')
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/vendors/'));
   });
2. Where should I copy eg. src/vendors/?

Thank you